# a Cypher with neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

please be gentleman!I am begginer in neo4j database. I know this `"START a=node({self}) MATCH a-[:FOLLOW]->(b) RETURN b"` return all following of {self} node but i want a cypher query that return all followers of a {self}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the direction of the relationship as shown below which indicates all b's that have follow relationship with {self}

```
START a=node({self}) MATCH a<-[:FOLLOW]-(b) RETURN b
```